# Google Earth API Usage In ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: .net, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I want to add google earth application to my asp.net web application.User can add placemark as they want and then save the places as ".kmz" or ".kml".What is the best way to integrate? Is it possible to load google earth application directly in asp.net? Or Do I need to use google earth API to get that kind of functions? Please share me if you have any sample application or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know asp.net. However, the Earth API only has a JavaScript component. So you would need to create JavaScript on your page to load it. Just Googling it, I came up with this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How ever I'm working on the same thing, yes you can add google earth in your asp.net web application for that you need to add the google earth api and install google earth plugin in your system. You can check out some examples where these are already done.

https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/examples

and for more check out documentation of google earth api

https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index